# Multiple backstacks are added to the fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android application, a fragment will be added to the activity by a certain action (for example, the action bar menu).

This is the code I add the fragment:

```
        case R.id.action_add_box:
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.place, BoxEditFragment.newInstance(null, null));
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            break;
```

Now once the user hit the action menu with id `action_add_box` two times, then he have to hit the back two times to close the fragment which is not expected.

Is it possible to avoid this?

For example, once user hit the action menu, do nothing if the fragment have been already visible to the user?

And one more question, there are some EditTexts in the fragment, once user complete, I will submit the data and close the fragment, however user may need to open the fragment again, and  I want to keep the value of the EditText as last entered by user. Now I save the values when the fragment are detached and reset the value when created using the `savedInstanceState`.

Also create a new instance of the fragment for each action command is a waste of memory, I wonder if I can use only one fragment instance, then I may not need to save/reset the values manually?

Comment: May be store ft.commit() result and look at this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(int, int)

Answer (score 0):

you can use singleton parttern to keep one instance of fragment for eg:

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

      public static MyFragment oneInstance = null ;


       private MyFragment(){
        super();
       }

      public static MyFragment getInstance(){
         if (oneInstance == null ){
          synchronized (MyFragment.class){
            if ( oneInstance == null ){
                 oneInstance = new MyFragment();
             }
          }
         return oneInstance ;

      }

}
```

the above code is also thread safe

```
 MyFragment frag= (MyFragment )getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_layout);


   if(frag == null){

      // fragment is not visible
   }else{

      // fragment is visible

   }
```